# SQL Server Isolation Level And Table Locking

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

So let's say I have a table in SQL server that serves as a queue for items that need processing.  Something like this:

```
Id (bigint)
BatchGuid (guid)
BatchProcessed (bit)
...
```

...along with some other columns describing the item that needs to be processed, etc.  So there are many running consumers that add records to this table as needed to indicate that an item needs to be processed.

So now let's say I have a job that is in charge of getting a batch of items from this table and processing them.  Say we want to let it process 10 at a time.  Now also assume that this job can have many instances running at once, so it is concurrently accessing the table (along with any other consumers who may be adding new records to the queue).

I was planning to do something like this:

```
using(var tx = new Transaction(Isolation.Serializable))
{
    var batchGuid = //newGuid
    executeSql("update top(10) [QUeueTable] set [BatchGuid] = batchGuid where [BatchGuid] is null");
    var itemsToProcess = executeSql("select * from [QueueTable] where [BatchGuid] = batchGuid");
    tx.Commit()
}
```

So basically what I'd be doing is starting a transaction as serializable, marking 10 items with a specific GUID, then getting those 10 items, then committing.

Is this a feasible strategy?  I believe the isolation level of serializable will basically lock the whole table to prevent read/write until the transaction is complete - is this correct?  Basically the transaction will block all other read/write operations on the table?  I believe this is what I want in this case as I don't want to read dirty data and I don't want concurrent running jobs to stomp on each other when marking a batch of 10 to process.

Any insights as to whether I'm on the right track with this would be much appreciated.  If there are better ways to accomplish this I'd welcome alternatives as well.

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: That is a fantastic write up, Remus.  Very informative!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single statement if you use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause:

```
UPDATE TOP (10) [QueueTable]
OUTPUT inserted.*
SET [BatchGuid] = batchGuid 
WHERE [BatchGuid] IS NULL;
```

Or more specifically:

```
var itemsToProcess = executeSql("update top(10) [QUeueTable] output inserted.* set [BatchGuid] = batchGuid where [BatchGuid] is null");
```

It is personally preference I suppose, but I have never been a fan of the `UPDATE TOP(n)` syntax, because you can't specify an `ORDER BY`, and in most cases when specfifying top, you want to specify an order by, I much prefer using something like:

```
UPDATE  q
OUTPTUT inserted.*
SET     [BatchGuid] = batchGuid 
FROM    (   SELECT  TOP (10) *
            FROM    dbo.QueueTable
            WHERE   BatchGuid IS NULL
            ORDER BY ID
        ) AS q
```

**ADDENDUM**

In response to the comment, I don't believe there is any chance of a race condition, but I was not 100% certain. The reason I don't believe this because although the query reads as a SELECT, and an UPDATE, it is syntactic sugar, it is just an update, and uses exactly the same plan, and locks as the top query. However, since I don't know for sure I decided to test:

First I set up a sample table in temp DB, and a logging table to log updated IDs

```
USE TempDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Col UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL);
INSERT dbo.T (Col)
SELECT TOP 1000000 NULL
FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T2 (ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then in 10 different SSMS windows I ran this:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

    UPDATE  T
    SET     Col = @ID
    OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO dbo.T2 (ID)
    FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 10 *
                FROM    dbo.T
                WHERE   Col IS NULL
                ORDER BY ID
            ) t;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN;
END
```

The whole process ran for 20 minutes updating ~500,000 rows before I stopped all 10 threads. Since updating the same row twice would throw and error when inserting to T2 as a primary key violation, and all 10 threads needed to be stopped this shows that there was no race condition, and to confirm this, I ran the following:

```
SELECT Col, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.T
WHERE Col IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Col
HAVING COUNT(*) <> 10;
```

Which, as expected, returned no rows.

I am happy to be proved wrong and to concede I was lucky in that none of these 100,000 iterations clashed, but I don't believe it was luck. I really believe there is a single lock, therefore it doesn't matter if you have a transaction or not, you just need the correct isolation level.

Comment: Awesome.  Thx for that tip I've never seen the OUTPUT keyword before.  Would this still require a transaction with serializable isolation level?  Is there a possibility of deadlocking or anything like that?

Comment: No need for the transaction, you are no more likely to get a conflict than you would be updating the rows without the output.

Comment: Sounds good, GarethD.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't agree about "No need for the transaction".   Try to execute that piece of code in two different processes, both executing your code in a loop. It won't work. If you wrap the code in a transaction, it will result in a deadlock. You NEED to wrap in a transaction and change SELECT top(10) * from table     with      SELECT top(10) * from table WITH (UPDLOCK)

Comment: If someone disagrees, I'd like to know why, instead of having an anonymous downvote.

Comment: @ildanny I appreciate the non-anonymous down vote, I have added an edit to justify why I think only a single lock is taken, and the SQL for how I have tested it. Based on your percentages of 40% of rows being processed twice, it seems (to me anyway) unfathomable that I would get to c.50k iterations with no error if there was a chance of a race condition.

Comment: You are wrong about the number of lock, but I was wrong as well because the OUTPUT CLAUSE changes the behaviour of the subquery. If you enable the lock debug on you script, a single update/output will create more than 90 locks. If you remove OUTPUT, S-Locks are requested instead of IX-Locks and you will incur in concurrency problems. In any case the subquery creates its own lock.

Answer (score 1):

Serializable isolation mode does not necessarily lock the whole table. If you have an index on BatchGuid you will probably do ok, but if not then SQL will probably escalate to a table lock.

A few things you may want to look at:

- Using the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) statement you can combine your UPDATE and SELECT into one query
- You may need to use [UPDLOCK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table) if you have multiple processes running this query